# I need a way to fill up empty spaces on the left and right of links

Tags: html, css

I need to auto fill spaces next to menu links.
I have a unknown number of links that make up a menu bar.

I need a way to fill in the empty space next to the links in a way that it looks exactly like the link.

If you have a look at my fiddle you will see there are green and black links classed:
a.menu(green) and a.menu_filler(black). I set them Green and Black to make it obvious which links I am talking about in the end they will have the same background.

I need the a.menu_filler(black) links to self adjust to 100% of the remaining width of the navbar div called div.navbar (silver).

http://jsfiddle.net/RFZees/Gt4SG/6/

I hope my explanation is understandable.

HTML:

```
<div class='navbar'> 
 <a class='menu_filler'></a>
 <a class='menu' href='#'>LINK</a>
 <a class='menu' href='#'>BIGGER LINK</a>
 <a class='menu' href='#'>BIGGEST LINK</a>
 <a class='menu_filler'></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.navbar {
    background:silver;
    height:50px;
    width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
a.menu_filler {
    background:black;
    height:30px;
    width:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
}
a.menu {
    background:green;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    color:blue;
}
a.menu:hover {
    background:blue;
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display: table;` and `border-spacing: 10px;` in .navbar, and then declare every `<a/>` element as `display:table-cell;`.

This way the fillers will be automatically calculated, the space between divs will be auto-adjusted, and they will be transparent.

Code

```
div.navbar {
    /* all your stuff */
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

div.navbar > a{
  display: table-cell;  
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nWzqc/

Comment: Ho Snap... I see what you did there. 
LOL It is kinda what I want but...

in the actual menu the navbar background is transparent. 
And the menu links have a transparent background tile image... 
I appologise for the misleading post I should have been more, "urm... transparent" about what I need.

More to the point... 
[link] http://jsfiddle.net/RFZees/Gt4SG/11/

Comment: SUCSESS!!! 
Thank you very much @Andrea Ligios for the help appreciate it. 
It makes all the links auto adjust.
A little different from how I had it in my head but it works very well and thus far this is the only option that works at all to give me the same effect.

Answer (score -4):

Add `display: table-cell;` to `a` and remove height from `div.navbar`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gt4SG/10/)**

Comment: Thanx, Anonymous @user2253835 

This actually fixes a margin-top:- 18px; problem I had due to the padding. 
I want the spaces between the links bigger than the space between navbar and the content container below it. 

THANX!!!